# EditText focus inconsistent across layouts

Tags: android, xml, orientation

I have two different main.xml files, one for portrait, one for layout. Each one has this code inside of a RelativeLayout inside of a Scrollview.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_phone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/acquire"
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="observer name"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/phone"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"               
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="phone number"
        android:nextFocusDown="@id/phone"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

etc ...

The oddity is this: as far as I know, you are not supposed to be able to refer to things that haven't happened yet in xml, so android:nextFocusDown="@id/phone" should fail because phone hasnt been declared; and that is what happens in my landscape xml but not in portrait. In portrait it works perfectly and passes the focus through all four EditTexts with no hitch. If I put the NextFocusDown into the landscape, it will fail to compile, stating "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'nextFocusDown' with value '@id/phone')."

A solution or explanation would be great. The idea is that I have four text boxes in two different LinearLayouts and whichever one has focus first will pass it to the EditText beneath it, skipping the others. I want it to work as I have it in portrait layout, when the user hits next on the name, focus moves to phone, when they hit next on that it moves to email, etc. I'm also curious as to why it is letting this work in portrait but not landscape.

Comment: i answered this kind of quest here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994772/edittexts-androidnextfocusdown-attibute-stops-working-when-onclick-is-set/8701529#8701529 may be it helpful for others

Comment: good suggestion but i was already aware of that solution, i just try to avoid setting up the gui elements programatically. also it does not answer my question, which is why does it work in one situation but not in the other. your comment is still appreciated though as it probably will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 22):

This is a really old post but I'm answering it as best I can. From what I know you put the + sign the first time you are referencing the id, so on your:
`android:nextFocusDown="@id/phone"` should actually be `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/phone` because it is the first time you are referencing that object. Then take out the + sign where you have 
`android:id="@+id/phone"`

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as so!

Comment: The example from Handle Tab Navigation https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/navigation.html#Tab also illustrates this.

Answer (score 7):

You are using "@id/phone" try using "@+id/phone" the + is necessary to reference the id of the object

Comment: you are incorrect.

"The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file)."

[Declaring Layout from developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id)

while i did make a mistake with `android:nextFocusDown="@id/phone"` it was unrelated to the problem i was asking about.

Comment: Sound logical, but when I don't use the + symbol, it won't build because of errors in the layout file. (No resource found that matches the given name)

Comment: I gave this comment an upvote because it is correct.  If you are specifying nextFocusDown and the element with that id hasn't been declared yet you use the @+id notation.  Then when you declare the element that you want to assign that id you use the @id notation. Creating an id and creating the element that has that id are two very different things.

Comment: I upvote. It is correct. Is the same as put views inside relativeLayout. If you want to use '@id/' you must declare the id in ids.xml