# EditText´s android:nextFocusDown attibute stops working when onClick is set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Does anybody knows why the android:nextFocusDown attibute stops working when we set the onClick on it?

On the example below, we have some EditText with this attribute defined:

```
<TableRow
android:weightSum="1"
android:gravity="center">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtChave1"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtChave2"></EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtChave2"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtChave3"></EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtChave3"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtChave4"></EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtChave4"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"></EditText>
</TableRow>
```

As defined above, when user clicks on the "next button" on virtual keyboard, the focus changes as expected... But, if we set the onClick attribute, the **android:nextFocusDown** doen´t work anymore.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/txtChave1"
android:maxLength="4"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight=".23"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:singleLine="true"
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/txtChave2"
android:onClick="onClickHandler">
</EditText>
```

Any advice?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Either I don't know what the "next button" is, or today every code with focus problems, works on my side from the provided samples! Your code works on my emulator. Sorry for asking, but you have defined a method with signature public void onClickHandler(View view), right?

Comment: Hi @hovanessyan, thanks for your comment.
The "next button" means the "Enter Button" on Virtual Keyboard. The signature to the onClickHandler is also as you said.

Please give a try. On your emulator, run the code without the public  onClickHandler, pressing the "Next Button". Everything should work. After, put the onClickHandler on all EditTexts and try to navigate between them using the "Next Button". You´ll note that the focus will not change to the next EditText as expected.

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: ok, so for temporary solution, can't you just define the onClick listeners programmatically and move on?

Comment: Actually why would you want to have a onClick handler on EditText?

Comment: Hi @hovanessyan! There is two EditText that should be used on a filter. But, the filter should be performed using the content of one OR other field. So, if the user clicks on the second EditText, the first should be cleaned. If the user clicks on the first, the second should be cleaned also.

Thanks!

Comment: Than, is it possible to use onFocusChangeListener instead of onClick?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do it programmatically because when you call `android:nextFocusDown` in XML may be the object that you want to call in the nextFocus will not create it till.

```
private void setUpView(){
    editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
}

private void setUpFocus(){
    editText1.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.editText2);
    editText2.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.editText8);// you can give focus to any id
    editText3.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.editText9);
}
```

Call `setUpView()` before `setUpFocus()` in `onCreate()`.

Comment: Good Job. It solved my problem. I coded it in xml but it didn't work. But It worked by coding in .java/.kt file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently and found out that it will work if you use setOnTouchListener instead of setOnClickListener. In the onTouch method use MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN or MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, according to what you need. Also don't forget to return FALSE for events that also have to be processed by the system (if you want to be safe, always return false).